# Can we use custom keyboards in Telegram with Rasa?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, rasa

I would like to integrate Rasa into Telegram’s messaging platform, however I would also like to utilize their custom keyboard feature that Telegram provides. Does anybody know whether it’s possible and maybe have example or resources to?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, Rasa supports `inline`, `vertical`, and `reply` keyboards. I see that the Telegram API references the "new" custom keyboards -- not sure how new they are.

https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/master/rasa/core/channels/telegram.py#L51

If you want to do something with keyboards that isn't currently supported in Rasa Open Source, I'm sure a contribution would be accepted for that as well.